# iOS - Downloading Video Data from Parse

Tags: objective-c, parse-platform, avfoundation, nsdata

I am trying to download a PFFile which is a tfss file(?). It gets opened as a text file. This is the code I use for retrieveing the data:

```
-(void) queryVideoWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionary {
    PFQuery *videoQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"EventVideos"];
    [videoQuery whereKey:@"objectId" equalTo:[dictionary objectForKey:@"videoId"]];
    [videoQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *results, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            PFFile *videoFile = [results[0] objectForKey:@"video"];
            [videoFile getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    NSString *dataString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                  //  NSURL *movieURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:dataString];

                    NSMutableDictionary *videoDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObject:data forKey:[dictionary objectForKey:@"videoId"]];
                    [self.videoArray addObject:videoDictionary];

                    NSLog(@"video array count: %ld", self.videoArray.count);

                    NSLog(@"dataString: %@", dataString);
                //    NSLog(@"movieURL: %@", movieURL);
                    [self.player setItemByStringPath:dataString];
                    [self.player play];
                });          
            }];
        } else {
            NSLog(@"error");
        }  
    }];
}
```

When `dataString` gets logged, it returns null, so I don't know how to get the data and play it as a video. It is saved as a QuickTimeMovie by the way.
I use SCRecorder to play and record videos.

Edit: `data` is definitely not nil, I still don't know how to solve this issue.

Comment: Is the error in `getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:` background nil?

Comment: Yes, it returns no error @Larme

Comment: Is data nil? Could you log it? Is videoFile nil?

Comment: This is the log from videoFile: videoFile: <PFFile: 0x7fbb4419eea0> This is data: data: <00000014 66747970 71742020 00000000 71742020 00000008. I couldn't log the whole data since its extremely long @Larme

Comment: Are you sure data is string transformable?

Comment: No I am not, but I read it on an other question on SO and this was suggested to do. Do you know how I could play the data? I can play it in QuickTimePlayer when I add a .mov to the downloaded file. @Larme

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109449/discussion-between-strikecounter2-and-larme).